# Sum of Uniform([-1, 1]) random variables is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d $\text{Uniform}([-1, 1])$ random variables. Let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Show that almost surely, the set $\{S_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I wonder if there is a way to approach this problem with the Kolmogorov's 0-1 law or the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law? Besides, I think the Borel-Cantelli lemma could also be useful to solve this problem.

Comment: I think it would be easier to show that every rational number is in the closure

Comment: This is well known result based on properties of random walks. See for example Section 5.4 of Durret's Probability theory and examples (5th edition, Cambridge U. Press). The random walk you described is recurrent and since the distribution of $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ has positive density in $(-n,n)$, every point  is a possible value of the random walk. The recurrent points is a closed subgroup of ℝ which coincides with the set of possible values (Chung-Fuch's theorem). The treatment of random walks uses the Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law.

Comment: @Mittens I have looked at Durrett and I think theorem 5.4.1 is the result that you mentioned here. However, I still wonder how to formally show that the set of all possible values of the random walk (i.e the set $\mathcal{U}$ mentioned in Durrett) in this case is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$? In particular, how to find a subset $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathcal{U}$, $\epsilon > 0$, we have that: $$\mathbb{P}(\sup_n |S_n - x | < \epsilon) > 0$$ Thank you very much for your answer again!

Comment: @Harry: The density of $S_n$ is the convolution of $\frac12\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$ with itself $n$-times.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to answer the question of the OP regarding the carrier of $S_n$, where  $S_n=\sum^n_{j=1}X_j$.
Denote $B(x;\varepsilon)=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

If $B(x;\varepsilon)\subset[-n,n]$, then
$$\{S_n\in B(x;\varepsilon)\}\supset\bigcap^n_{j=1}\Big\{X_j\in B\big(\frac{x}{n};\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\big)\Big\}$$
Notice  that $B(x/n;\varepsilon/n)\subset(-1,1)$.
Since the $X_n$'s are iid with distribution $U(-1,1)$,
$$\mathbb{P}[|S_n-x|<\varepsilon]\geq\prod^n_{j=1}P\Big[\Big|X_j-\frac{x}{n}\Big|<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\Big]=\Big(\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\Big)^n>0$$

The solution of the OP then follows from classical results for random walks as stated in my comment.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that taking the supremum over all $|S_n - x|$ would give the same result by continuity of measure?